# Android, ConstraintLayout: position views one after another while maintaining constraints

Tags: android, listview, android-constraintlayout

I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

Basically, I have a layout with an header and a footer already in it. I need to put 1 ListView and 2 Views inside the remaining space so that:

- ListView starts at the top and fill all available space
- View1 is right after ListView
- View2 is right after View1
- if ListView is not visible (or very short), the Views should appear
  at the top of the screen.
- ListView should expand to screen_heigth -header -footer -view1 -view2

I tried every possible chain combination, putting views inside linearLayouts, using only constraints and bias, but the closest thing I got is to have the views packed in the right order but centered instead of at the top of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"        
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_view" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

can anybody help me with this? I also can change the constraintLayout to something else if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `View1` and `View2` to stick to the bottom of the `ListView` even if the list is short and does not fill the whole remaining space then the `ListView's` height has to be set to `wrap_content`. To keep the three widgets aligned to the top you can create a vertical chain with style `packed` and vertical bias of `0`. This is an example layout using `TextViews` to show the idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/listview"
        tools:text="View 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1"
        tools:text="View 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Footer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want to the `ListView` to fill the remaining space regardless of its content just change its height to `0dp` and remove `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try to make a relativeLayout and inside of your Constraint layout